# Вопрос по построению архитектуры с 4 сервисами и rabbitmq

Tags: python, django, архитектура, rabbitmq, микросервисы

Стоит задача мне как `backend`-разработчику по работе улучшить архитектуру работы 4 сервисов, добавить своего рода отказоустойчивость и сохранение результатов при сбое приложений с восстановлением ранее отправленных запросов, поэтому хочу разобраться с правильным построением новой и правильной архитектуры, которую не пришлось бы позже переделывать и иметь возможность быстрый апскейлинг при нагрузке.

Предыстория:

Есть один большой монолит на `django`, который содержит какую-то информацию в базе данных.
В целом это дашборд компании с различными сервисами, и там около 20 `django`-приложений с локальной `postgres`.
Назовем его сервис A.

Допустим в 1 таблице сервиса А лежит ~ 20 записей, они редко изменяются, но в какой-то момент там данные могут быть изменены админом в админской части.

Есть сервис B, С, и D, это обычные веб-серверы либо на `flask` (`gunicorn`) либо `fastapi` (`uvicorn`) которые каждый раз делают десятки-сотни запросов на сервис A и получают эти ~ 20 записей, то есть условный `GET` данных, когда приходит какой-то запрос на сервис B, C или D.

Сервисы B, С и D не взаимосвязаны друг с другом, но в целом логика у них схожая. Каждый сервис содержит в себе локально свою `postres`-базу данных.

Когда сервисы B, C, или D обработали пришедшую на них ссылку с данными (в секунду может на каждый сервис приходить условно 50-100 запросов, иногда 5-10, в зависимости от ситуации, раньше нагрузки всегда были небольшими, около 5-10 запросов в с.) и каждый сервис обрабатывает условно каждый запрос за 0.2-0.3 секунды, но может занимать и 1-2 секунды, в общем делают какую-то работу, и отправляют в конце своей работы на сервис A запись в другую таблицу, что данный запрос успешно обработан и статус его либо 200 или, допустим, 400. В целом вопрос не в том, что запросов накапливается больше чем время, за которое может быть обработан запрос сервисом.

Были проблемы на стороне сервиса А, что логично, так как он стал перегружаться из-за постоянного извлечения данных с бд при каждом запросе из сервисов B C и D.
Сначала было решено сделать на сервисе А кэш на `n`-минут, так как данные особо не меняются. Это было сделано за счет `django.cache`, который добавлял этих ~ 20 записей в кэш и если приходит запрос, тогда он отдается с кэша в течение `n`-минут. Но если админ добавляет/меняет запись, тогда срабатывает `django`-сигнал на модель и удаляет данные с кэша, поэтому  при новом запросе данные просто снова добавляются в кэш, что решает часть проблемы с нагрузкой на базу. Но остается одна проблема на записи `POST`, потому что каждый сервис B C и D в конце работы отправляет `POST` запрос на A. Это в принципе не так критично.

Проблема следующая: сервисы B C и D испытывают большую нагрузку, от чего `gunicorn` может падать с ошибкой:

```
[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT pid (id процесса)
[INFO] Worker exiting
[INFO] Booting worker with pid
```

Поэтому часть логики при обработке каким-то сервисом просто не срабатывает, и данные уже получаются утерянными.

Нюанс в том, что сервис B, C и D подняты на 2 ядерном, 2 ядерном и 4 ядерном хосте соответственно. То есть для этих сервисов подняты 2 или 4 процесса. Например:

`gunicorn -b :5000 -w 2 app:app`

либо

`gunicorn -b :8000 -w 4 app:app`

Данные проксируются через `nginx` и попадают уже непосредственно на сервисы.

Критичен один из фактов, что уже есть ошибки, типа
`[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT pid`.

Но, в целом, не только в этом проблема, хочется решить для себя и разобраться, как строить хорошую архитектуру для таких приложений.

Вопрос. Как лучше переделать архитектуру сервисов B C и D? Есть мысль создать как-то это все на `rabbitmq` - ранее с ним не работал, но много посмотрел туториалов по настройке и вообще о его применении. В принципе `kafka` не нужна, так как там всего будет на всех 3 сервисах до 500 запросов, если взять вместе (условно).

Решений, которые я вижу, два:

1. В принципе есть мысль создать еще одни инстансы B C и D, но нужно как-то сделать согласованность базы данных на каждом инстансе. То есть как сделать так, чтобы при разворачивании нескольких инстансов одного и того же сервиса - база была согласованная? Отдельно нужно вынести базу данных, чтобы инстансы сервисов общались с ней, при этом использовать транзакции и блокировки базы? Вот этот нюанс пока что не понятен.
2. В целом была мысль сделать для отказоустойчивости по крохотному микросервису на каждый сервис (B, C, и D), который принимает запросы с `gunicorn`/`uvicorn` и кладет данные только в `rabbitmq` и это единственная его работа. `Router key` установлен в `direct` на каждый такой инстанс. Затем на каждом сервисе (B, C и D) вместо поднятого веб-сервера сделать потребителя, который забирает данные с очереди и уже делают какую-то работу, при этом на каждом из сервисов установлен `auto_ack=False`, чтобы подтвердить сообщение только тогда, если сервис реально рабочий, и тогда удалить его из `rabbitmq`. Насколько правильно понимаю - будет решена проблема сохранения запросов, то есть если "умрет" какой-то сервис, то микросервис будет сохранять данные в очередь до тех пор, пока не будет восстановлен какой-то из сервисов.

Также много начитался о том, что можно реализовать быстрый апскейл `rabbitmq` для повышения производительности, но пока не разобрался как. По-хорошему тут, наверное, нужно вынести все сервисы в контейнеры и закинуть в `k8s`, но знаний в оркестрации контейнеров пока что нет.

Правильный ли мой ход мыслей, разумно ли сюда вообще добавлять `rabbitmq`, как добиться хорошей отказоустойчивости?

Comment: Не думаю, что тут нужен rabbitmq. Проблема, судя по всему, в том, что worker процессы gunicorn-a не справляются под нагрузкой. Из того, что описали - они в основом ждут на операциях ввода-вывода (т.е. делают запросы по к БД и другому сервису).  Проверить можно посмотрев на загрузку процессора под такой нагрузкой - если до 100% далеко, то дело именно в этом. В таком случае достаточно увеличить количество worker-ов. Сделайте это плавно, наблюдая за загрузкой процессора. В зависимости от соотношения операций ввода/вывода и cpu-bound операций, обычно можно сделать количество worker-ов в

Comment: 2-4 (иногда больше) раза больше чем количество ядер. Если процессор уже близок к 100% 
под нагрузкой (до или после такого увеличения), то нужно что-то из этого (можно все): 1. оптимизировать обработку запросов (тут много вариантов есть) 2. добавлять ресурсов (мощнее хосты с большим колич. ядер) 3. добавлять доп. хосты (это похоже на добавление ядер), а перед ними load balancer. Работь должны с общей БД. Если приложение сейчас нормально умеет обрабатывать параллельные запросы, то и тут проблем не будет.

Comment: Тот способ, который вы описали работы с rabbitmq, не поможет. Все равно обработчик веб запроса должен ждать, когда будет готов ответ. Все это время worker занят и ждет. Если время обработки привысит worker timeout (то что вы сейчас наблюдаете), будет та же проблема. Тут нужно менять схему работы на асинхронную (но это нельзя просто включить опцией - нужно, чтоб приложение умело обрабатывать запросы асинхронно, иначе будет та же проблема, но не на уровне обработчиков gunicorn, а на уровне пула потоков, которые заворачивают синхронные вызовы к приложению).

Comment: Ну и важно, что отказоустойчивость с http запросами не получится сама по себе, если клиент не умеет делать повторный запрос, а сервер не умеет понять, что это именно тот же запрос, и если он уже обработан, то просто вернуть готовый результат и не делать повторно ту же операцию. Если оборвется соединение или будет сбой на сервере во время запроса, то никакие ухищрения на сервере не помогут без поддержки (или точнее правильного поведения) со стороны клиента.  Решение этих проблем так же является и решением проблемы с временной неспособностью сервера справляться с нагрузкой.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Внимательно прочитал ваши комментарии. Нагрузка, если не ошибаюсь не доходила до 100%, но это надо будет проверить, когда будет пик нагрузок. 1 из 3 сервисов асинхронный (на fastapi с uvicorn). В целом нагрузки мизерные, если смотреть сейчас htop. Кажется, проблема в том, что один из API сервисов, когда делается запрос, например, на сервисе B, выполняется дольше стандартных 30 секунд у gunicorn, поэтому он и падает с worker timeout. Думаю повысить, как вы и сказали, количество воркеров до 4 на 2 ядерном хосте, понаблюдаю за результатами.

Comment: И думаю перепишем с flask на fastapi и поднимем uvicorn. Допустим, если проблема аналогичная останется с тем, что какой-то из API сервисов на моем сервисе (B, C или D) также отдает результат дольше 30 секунд - uvicorn асинхронные запросы не заблокируют воркер? По идее цикл событий asyncio переключал бы контекст между тасками и они не должны были бы выбить? Или ситуация останется такой же из-за таймаута?

Comment: Когда обработка запроса больше таймаута, то либо увеличивать таймаут (это влияет на другие запросы - они дольше ждут в очереди), либо мощнее процессор (если узкое место именно в cpu-bound операциях) или оптимизировать выполнение запроса или менять схему работу на асинхронную уже на уровне http (т.е. первый запрос - начинаем операцию, последуюющие - проверяем статус и получаем результат). Увеличение количества worker-ов, как я предлагал выше, поможет только другим запросам и только в случае, если узкое место ввод/вывод. Саму проблему с таймаутом для медленного запроса это не решит.

Comment: Переключение на asyncio или другой способ выполнять запросы асинхронно поможет т.к. при использовании asyncio таймауты уже не такая большая проблема (и их можно увеличить относительно безполезненно), т.к. запросы, которые долго работают не блокируют другие паралельные запросы.

Comment: Думаю, судя по всему проблема не в cpu-bound операциях, а именно в i/o. 2 воркера ждут i/o, а 3 запрос походу весит в очереди, пока не отработают другие 2 запроса, а они в свою очередь походу при запросах к API другого сервиса ждут дольше 30 секунд, вот и worker timeout, а они как раз и не асинхронные на gunicorn и flask. Проверю этот кейс. Окей, благодарю за ответы, думаю будем в дальнейшем переписывать на fastapi с uvicorn

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Но у меня остаются еще 2 вопроса: а если все-таки хочется создать несколько инстансов одного сервиса но бд общая, то все-таки разумно  выносить бд на какой-то хост, или оставить на одном из сервисов, но для других инстансов открыть ее просто наружу? Может разумнее делать через `minikube`? Это так, на будущее. А второй вопрос в том, что если все-таки перед сервисом поставить микросервис с rabbitmq, и пусть он отдает постоянно 200 и пишет данные в брокер. Если умирает сервис - запросы сохраняются в брокере до восстановления сервиса, или в этом нет особого смысла?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151552/discussion-between-roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua-and-denrudi).